# combine files consisting of two columns

Tags: perl, awk

I have multiple files that look like this:

file1:

```
rsRNA-2312-n    2
rsRNA-6508-n    2
rsRNA-6382-n    10
rsRNA-951-n 0
rsRNA-6330-n    4
rsRNA-6330-n    11
rsRNA-1385-n    3
rsRNA-4945-n    0
rsRNA-946-n 9
```

file2:

```
rsRNA-552-n 2
rsRNA-5301-n    7
rsRNA-6487-n    0
rsRNA-4945-n    7
rsRNA-2445-n    9
rsRNA-6490-n    2
```

file3:

```
rsRNA-4946-n    1
rsRNA-5058-n    0
rsRNA-552-n 0
rsRNA-849-n 2
rsRNA-3302-n    2
rsRNA-4099-n    0
rsRNA-552-n 1
```

I would like to merge the files creating a output that has the values for each input file in a separate column and unique identifier (column 1 in the input file) in column1. If an identifier is not found in a specific input file, the count should be 0 for this identifier for this specific input.

output like (not real data):

```
identifier   file1   file2    file3
rsRNA-552-n 2    4    5
rsRNA-5301-n    7   12    2
rsRNA-6487-n    0    1    5
rsRNA-4945-n    7   12   1
rsRNA-2445-n    9   4    55
rsRNA-6490-n    2  1    0
```

Was trying:

```
paste <(awk '{print $2}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $2}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $2}' file3) <(awk '{print $2}' file4)
```

and using a for loop:

```
for f in file*; do
base_name=${f%.txt}
id=${base_name#*_}
awk  > "output${id}"
done
```

Comment: But I have 96 files :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a shell loop to manipulate text is always the wrong approach. Just use awk, it's what it was designed to do. Using GNU awk 4.* for true multi-D arrays and ARGIND and sorted `in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($1,a,/-/)
    key = a[2]
    key2name[key] = $1
    key2val[key][ARGIND] = $2
}
END {
    printf "identifier"
    for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=ARGIND;fileNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, ARGV[fileNr]
    }
    print ""

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in key2name) {
        printf "%s", key2name[key]
        for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=ARGIND;fileNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, (fileNr in key2val[key] ? key2val[key][fileNr] : 0)
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
identifier file1 file2 file3
rsRNA-552-n 0 2 1
rsRNA-849-n 0 0 2
rsRNA-946-n 9 0 0
rsRNA-951-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-1385-n 3 0 0
rsRNA-2312-n 2 0 0
rsRNA-2445-n 0 9 0
rsRNA-3302-n 0 0 2
rsRNA-4099-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-4945-n 0 7 0
rsRNA-4946-n 0 0 1
rsRNA-5058-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-5301-n 0 7 0
rsRNA-6330-n 11 0 0
rsRNA-6382-n 10 0 0
rsRNA-6487-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-6490-n 0 2 0
rsRNA-6508-n 2 0 0
```

I added the slight additional complexity of the `key` as the numeric part of the first field so when outputting the results they can be sorted numerically on that sub-field.

Comment: But I have 96 files :/

Comment: @user2300940 you can use `awk -f tst.awk file*` where `file*` is generic expression from all 96 files

Comment: @user2300940 I showed it being used for 3 files - what makes you think you can't keep going and list 96 files or 5,000 files if you like?

Comment: Looks good, however, I only get 2 columns in my output. The files are stacked on top of each other

Comment: I don't know what `The files are stacked on top of each other` means. Debugging Step 1) are you using GNU awk version 4.0 or higher (`awk --version` will tell you). Step 2) Do you have spurious control characters in your files such as you would get if they were created on Windows (`cat -v file` will show them and `dos2unix` or similar will remove them).

Comment: awk version 20070501. I mean that the counts are not listed in separate columns for each input like in your example. I am on a mac btw.

Comment: `awk version 20070501` is not GNU awk. I'm very surprised the script doesn't fail with a syntax error given the array indexing constructs I used are gawk-specific. Get/use the current version of GNU awk: `awk --version` = GNU Awk 4.1.1 as without it you are missing a TON of extremely useful functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution ....

```
awk '
{ d[$1][FILENAME] = $2 }
END{
    line = "identifier";
    for (i=1; i in ARGV; i++) line = line OFS ARGV[i];
    print line
    for(i in d){
        line = i;
        for (j=1; j in ARGV; j++){
            if(ARGV[j] in d[i]) line = line OFS d[i][ARGV[j]]
            else line = line OFS 0
        }
        print line
    }
}' file1 file2 file3
```

you get:

```
identifier file1 file2 file3
rsRNA-946-n 9 0 0
rsRNA-4945-n 0 7 0
rsRNA-1385-n 3 0 0
rsRNA-2312-n 2 0 0
rsRNA-6382-n 10 0 0
rsRNA-951-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-6490-n 0 2 0
rsRNA-6330-n 11 0 0
rsRNA-5301-n 0 7 0
rsRNA-5058-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-4946-n 0 0 1
rsRNA-2445-n 0 9 0
rsRNA-552-n 0 2 1
rsRNA-6487-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-4099-n 0 0 0
rsRNA-849-n 0 0 2
rsRNA-3302-n 0 0 2
rsRNA-6508-n 2 0 0
```

Comment: awk '
{ d[$1][FILENAME] = $2 }
END{
    line = "identifier";
    for (i=1; i in ARGV; i++) line = line OFS ARGV[i];
    print line
    for(i in d){
        line = i;
        for (j=1; j in ARGV; j++){
            if(ARGV[j] in d[i]) line = line OFS d[i][ARGV[j]]
            else line = line OFS 0
        }
        print line
    }
}' rsRNA_N1_grep_cut_cutN1_grep_cut_N1_grep2_N1_grep_N1_* > out.csv

Comment: awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
 { >>>  d[$1][ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 2
awk: illegal statement at source line 2

Comment: That syntax error is because you aren't using GNU awk 4.0 or later.

Comment: @user2300940 my GNU awk version is 4.0.1