# Merge files with different row numbers

Tags: r, merge

I have multiple files that look like this:

file1:

```
rsRNA-2312-n     2
rsRNA-6508-n     2
rsRNA-6382-n    10
rsRNA-951-n      0
rsRNA-6330-n     4
rsRNA-6330-n    11
rsRNA-1385-n     3
rsRNA-4945-n     0
rsRNA-946-n      9
```

file2:

```
rsRNA-552-n      2
rsRNA-5301-n     7
rsRNA-6487-n     0
rsRNA-4945-n     7
rsRNA-2445-n     9
rsRNA-6490-n     2
```

file3:

```
rsRNA-4946-n     1
rsRNA-5058-n     0
rsRNA-552-n      0
rsRNA-849-n      2
rsRNA-3302-n     2
rsRNA-4099-n     0
rsRNA-552-n      1
```

I would like to merge the files creating a output that has the values for each input file in a separate column and unique identifier (column 1 in the input file) in column1. If an identifier is not found in a specific input file, the count should be 0 for this identifier for this specific input.

output like (not real data):

```
identifier   file1   file2   file3
rsRNA-552-n      2       4       5
rsRNA-5301-n     7      12       2
rsRNA-6487-n     0       1       5
rsRNA-4945-n     7      12       1
rsRNA-2445-n     9       4      55
rsRNA-6490-n     2       1       0
```

Was trying:

```
files <- list.files(path = "./bowtie_mapped/", pattern='rsRNA_N1_grep_cut_cutN1_grep_cut_N1_grep2_N1_grep_N1*')

merged.data.frame = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), files)
```

and:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(files,
                      function(f) {
                        cbind(read.csv(f), file_name=f)
                      }))
```

Comment: Are the rownames unique in each file?

Comment: Some row.names occur in more than one file

Comment: I meant, can they occure more than once in a single file, sorry.

Comment: No. just once, sorry. I see that this is not the case in the example, but I will merge those that are not unique.

Comment: Maybe you could help with that as well? taking the sum of all non-unique row.names?

Comment: can you provde sample input?

Comment: Why did you ask this identical question twice - once tagged with r (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32777703/1745001) and the other with awk and perl (http://stackoverflow.com/q/32770802/1745001)? How many more times have you asked it with different tags???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the names occur only once in a file, you do the following:

```
library(data.table)
# make a list of filenames
file.list <- list.files(path = "./bowtie_mapped/", pattern='rsRNA*')
# read all the files
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv)
dt <- rbindlist(df.list, idcol = "id")

dtnew <- dcast(dt, V1 ~ id, value.var = "V2", fun.aggregate = sum, fill = 0)
```

this results in:

```
              V1  1 2 3
 1: rsRNA-1385-n  3 0 0
 2: rsRNA-2312-n  2 0 0
 3: rsRNA-2445-n  0 9 0
 4: rsRNA-3302-n  0 0 2
 5: rsRNA-4099-n  0 0 0
 6: rsRNA-4945-n  0 7 0
 7: rsRNA-4946-n  0 0 1
 8: rsRNA-5058-n  0 0 0
 9: rsRNA-5301-n  0 7 0
10:  rsRNA-552-n  0 2 1
11: rsRNA-6330-n 15 0 0
12: rsRNA-6382-n 10 0 0
13: rsRNA-6487-n  0 0 0
14: rsRNA-6490-n  0 2 0
15: rsRNA-6508-n  2 0 0
16:  rsRNA-849-n  0 0 2
17:  rsRNA-946-n  9 0 0
18:  rsRNA-951-n  0 0 0
```

---

The same result can be achieved with the `dplyr`/`tidyr` combination:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dfnew <- bind_rows(file.list, .id = "id") %>% 
  group_by(id, V1) %>% 
  summarise(V2=sum(V2)) %>% 
  spread(id, V2, fill=0)
```

Comment: What if I have 96 inputs?

Comment: @user2300940 you can also create a list with `list.files()`

Comment: Error in rbindlist(file.list, idcol = "id") : 
  unused argument (idcol = "id")

Comment: @user2300940 Which version of `data.table` are you using? You need the [latest version (v1.9.6)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) from CRAN in order to be able to use of the `idcol` parameter.

Comment: I am using 1.9.6, but idcol is not an option in this function

Comment: @user2300940 Strange, it works on my system. For reference, see [point 8 under 'new features' for v1.9.6](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). What happens when you remove `data.table`, restart R and install it again?

Comment: @user2300940 I also added a `dplyr`/`tidyr` alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90608/discussion-between-user2300940-and-jaap).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you that pre-process the data.

You can use the Reduce/merge-solution you already found with pre-processing of the data

Using merge:

```
alldata <- lapply(files, function(x){
  #read in data
  data <- read.table(text=x,header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
  #aggregate data
  data2 <- dcast(V1~"value",value.var="V2",fun.agg=sum,data=data)
  return(data2)
})

res <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="V1",all=TRUE), alldata)
```

If you want more control on where certain values came from, you can also use reshape with a file-identifier. Note that in the merge-solution I iterated over *files*, here I iterate over *file-names.*

```
#create a long dataframe including an origin
alldata <- do.call(rbind,lapply(names(files), function(x){
  #read in data
  data <- read.table(text=files[[x]],header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
  #aggregate data
  data2 <- dcast(V1~"value",value.var="V2",fun.agg=sum,data=data)
  data2$origin <- x
  return(data2)
})
)

res <- dcast(V1~origin,value.var="value",data=alldata)
```

data used: a list of text-strings

```
files <- structure(list(file1 = "rsRNA-2312-n     2\nrsRNA-6508-n     2\nrsRNA-6382-n    10\nrsRNA-951-n      0\nrsRNA-6330-n     4\nrsRNA-6330-n    11\nrsRNA-1385-n     3\nrsRNA-4945-n     0\nrsRNA-946-n      9", 
    file2 = "rsRNA-552-n      2\nrsRNA-5301-n     7\nrsRNA-6487-n     0\nrsRNA-4945-n     7\nrsRNA-2445-n     9\nrsRNA-6490-n     2", 
    file3 = "rsRNA-4946-n     1\nrsRNA-5058-n     0\nrsRNA-552-n      0\nrsRNA-849-n      2\nrsRNA-3302-n     2\nrsRNA-4099-n     0\nrsRNA-552-n      1"), .Names = c("file1", 
"file2", "file3"))
```

Comment: Error: value.var (V2) not found in input

Comment: [You've already accepted an answer, so not really necessary anymore, but for clarity]. My solution runs on my machine with the data in the current format. If there is headers in the original data, you should edit the code accordingly. As they are not in the given example, I didn't include them.